# MySql - Need Help for Deleting with Sub query

Tags: mysql

i want to delete some information of my Database. But my Code delete all Stuff in my Database. This is the Code:

```
delete ri1
from vergleichs_tabelle as ri1
inner join vergleichs_tabelle as ri2
on ri2.Datei2 = ri1.Datei1 AND ri2.Datei1 = ri1.Datei2
```

Comment: Where's your `where` condition? State exactly what you want to delete. This query in fact deletes all the records from `vergleichs_tabelle` table.

Answer (score 0):

delete from table_name where id='23';